# AFNetworking: Can't Get New Data After A POST Request

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm new with AFNetworking so I've never faced this problem before with NSURLConnection

I'm using this method after a post request to add category

```
-(void)getCategories{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSString * url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@v2/api/tags",kURL];
    NSDictionary *parameters =[self parameterBuild];
    [manager GET:url parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        categories = [responseObject objectForKey:@"tags"];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

}
```

And the problem is.. responseObject is always getting the old data for a while as if it's caching or something..

any help will be appreciated

Comment: maybe server supports caching?

Comment: You should realize that the statement: `categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` is useless because the next statement completely replaces the `categories` pointer. You really need to know exactly what every like of code you write does and why it is needed.

Comment: categories could be not initialized yet!!

Comment: @MohamedEmadHegab That's not how variables work. Echoing Zaph, I would strongly encourage you to read up on [Apple's Objective-C References](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html) to clarify any confusion on what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes, because you're not cleaning up the data and reloading view on error.

```
-(void)getCategories{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSString * url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@v2/api/tags",kURL];
    NSDictionary *parameters =[self parameterBuild];
    [manager GET:url parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        categories = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"tags"] mutableCopy];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        categories = [NSMutableArray new];
        // Reload view here, like you do for success
    }];
}
```

Comment: sorry can't get it .. why should i clean on error.. while i have no error!

Comment: You have written "After A POST Failed", so when it's failed you need to cleanup, otherwise OLD data will be rendered

Comment: i don't need to i'm looking to categories itself .. it display old data for a while